# GridView rows height are not same size

Tags: android, gridview

In my app I use a GridView but my values for each cells are not same size, when I put my values in GridView, it automatically set a size for all cells(I think it consider first cell height for all cells), can you tell me how can I fix that?
[image]

GridView Adapter:

Comment: gridview or grid layout?

Comment: post xml layout?

Comment: @Xenolion It's gridview

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use custom view your row Item in `Gridview`

```
public class SquareRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

  public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public SquareRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
   {
    if (widthMeasureSpec < heightMeasureSpec) 
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    else
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
  }
}
```

**In GridView row XML**

```
<SquareRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/descr_image"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</SquareRelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Nima.S-H Try above solution

Comment: It return NullPointerException for getting view ( view child)

Comment: @Nima.S-H I have tried it. It's working good Ok...Try above one solution

Answer (score 0):

I suggest please use `RecyclerView` with `StaggeredGridLayoutManager`, Throw this you can get layout same which you draw upside,

This is the link which will help you: 
https://android--code.blogspot.in/2015/12/android-recyclerview.html